# Error after saving or updating post

Tags: posts, headers

I am getting the following error every time I update or save a post:

> Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in /home/hridayay/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1850
>
> Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in /home/hridayay/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1850
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/hridayay/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:1850) in
>   /home/hridayay/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

I didn't modify any of the files mentionned, so I tried looking in my functions.php to see if there were any whitespaces after or before the php tag, but it didn't solve the problem... Any idea?

Comment: does it also happen with plugins disabled and a core-bundled theme active?

Comment: Now, but I cannot find where it is coming from, so for now I ended up putting a @ before the faulty line